# Jump conditions on interior boundaries

Tags: finite-element

I can not undrestand when we have jump on interior boundaries, if the solution be continuous. In  the interior boundaries, derivatives have only different unit outward normal vector and this means we can discard all interior derivatives terms. But in some text i see that they are different and the notation of $[\frac {\partial u}{\partial n}]=\frac {\partial u^+}{\partial n}-\frac{\partial u^-}{\partial n}$ is used. Is it related to the test space?
In fact, I am working on adaptive finite element methods for Poisson's equation, based on the book: *The finite element method,Theory,implementations and applications  written by M. larson and F. Bengzon,*  and on this book to find a posteriori error estimate for this equation by linear fem, they used jump for $\frac {\partial u}{\partial n}$
$$\eta_k=h_k\| f+\Delta u_h\|_{L^2(k)}+\frac{1}{2}h_k^{\frac{1}{2}}\|[n.\nabla u_h]\|_{L^2({\partial k}-\partial{\Omega})}$$

Comment: This should really be my field, but your question is so terse that I cannot figure out what exactly it is you are asking. Can you elaborate? In particular, please provide some more context to your question, such as where these jumps appear, bilinear forms that contain them, links to papers, etc.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth , thanks a lot for your comments. You were rigth. I added some more things on it an hope to be enough

Comment: In your jump condition, should it be $u$ or $u_h$? The exact solution might indeed be sufficiently smooth (not just continuous) for the jump term to vanish, but why do you expect that to be true for the finite element solution?

Comment: It sounds like you might be asking about Discontinuous Galerkin (DG) methods. Is that correct?

Comment: I think no and I am surprised because of that

Comment: Do you enforce _global_ ${\cal C}^1$ continuity for your discrete solution $u^h$? If not, e.g., if  the weaker condition $u^h \in {\cal C}^0(\Omega)$ holds, then the normal _gradient_ $\nabla u^h \cdot \vec{n}$ may well have jumps across elements - hence the estimator formula is correct.